# Map space key to go into insert mode

Tags: vim

I am trying to map my space key to make the Vim go into insert mode from normal mode.

The reason I want to do this is because sometimes I forget that I'm in normal mode and start typing as if I'm in insert mode. When I press the space key in between or even in the start of the page, it moves down and something or the other types due to the possibility of a press `a` or `i` in what I just typed.

So to avoid this I want to map my space key to insert mode from normal mode as we press `i` to do so.

I tried the following:

```
map space :i
map <space> :i
```

But these doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I bet this problem will go away if you use vim enough.  At some point muscle memory will kick in and you will be so used to vim it'll be second-nature.

Comment: Notice that `<S>` is not `<space>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're mixing up the modes in your mappings; that's an important concept in Vim. Though there's a `:startinsert` Ex command in Vim (where your mapping would indeed start with a `:`), it's more straightforward to use the *normal mode* `i` command:

```
:nnoremap <Space> i
```

You only want a *normal mode* mapping here, so `:nmap`, not `:map`; cp. `:help map-modes`. And see `:help key-notation` for why it's written `<Space>`.

Finally: [You should always use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Answer (score 8):

strange requirement, but, you have your reason. :)

try this line out:

```
nnoremap <space> i
```

Comment: It is strange, but [`<Space>`'s "normal" `Normal` mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#<Space>) is exactly the same a [`l`'s](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#l), so at least you're not really blocking any standard functionality. I've seen a lot worse :)

Comment: @John: Thanks :) I would surely think about it, if space <insert mode>, will create any problem.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Actually, not quite: `<Space>` wraps around lines, `l` doesn't.